# How much of the Virgin GlobalFlyer's L/D is due to laminar flow?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, drag, laminar-flow

Despite travelling much faster than the Voyager, it has a significantly higher L/D. The latter seems to have two features that disrupt laminate flow, that are absent in the former. Namely the canards and the fire propellers.

Anyway, how much of the 37 L/D was due to laminar flow? How much greater would total drag have been without it?